# Build error linked to TrustZone on MPLAB X for PIC32CM Microchip

Tags: pic, mplab

I am working on a project on a Microchip PIC32CM LS00, trying to run a code found on GitHub (https://github.com/Microchip-MPLAB-Harmony/csp_apps_pic32cm_le_ls, specifically the "TrustZone basic demonstration - PIC32CMLS00" sample project). When importing the project on MPLAB X IDE v6.05 and attempting to build it, I obtain the following error message:

```
make -f nbproject/Makefile-test.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '[...]/test/NonSecure/firmware/test_NonSecure.X'
cd ../../../Secure/firmware/test_Secure.X && make  -f Makefile CONF=test
make[2]: Entering directory '[...]/test/Secure/firmware/test_Secure.X'
make -f nbproject/Makefile-test.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[3]: Entering directory '[...]/test/Secure/firmware/test_Secure.X'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-test.mk dist/test/production/test_Secure.X.production.hex
make[4]: Entering directory '[...]/test/Secure/firmware/test_Secure.X'
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"   -mprocessor=32CM5164LS00064  -o dist/test/production/test_Secure.X.production.elf build/test/production/_ext/683504921/plib_clock.o build/test/production/_ext/681355435/plib_evsys.o build/test/production/_ext/1363761897/plib_nvic.o build/test/production/_ext/1738829865/plib_nvmctrl.o build/test/production/_ext/208636476/plib_pm.o build/test/production/_ext/1363815048/plib_port.o build/test/production/_ext/1918410531/xc32_monitor.o build/test/production/_ext/340140899/exceptions.o build/test/production/_ext/340140899/initialization.o build/test/production/_ext/340140899/interrupts.o build/test/production/_ext/340140899/libc_syscalls.o build/test/production/_ext/340140899/startup_xc32.o build/test/production/_ext/1903470166/nonsecure_entry.o build/test/production/_ext/1360937237/main.o          -DXPRJ_test=test      -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1,--script="..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld",--defsym=_min_heap_size=0,--gc-sections,-Map="dist/test/production/test_Secure.X.production.map",--memorysummary,dist/test/production/memoryfile.xml -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS00"
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin"\\xc32-bin2hex dist/test/production/test_Secure.X.production.elf 
..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld:143:4: warning: #warning "Defaulting to a SECURE TrustZone-M project. Please define the linker macro SECURE, NONSECURE, or SECURE_BOOTLOADER (e.g. -Wl,-DSECURE)." [-Wcpp]
 #  warning "Defaulting to a SECURE TrustZone-M project. Please define the linker macro SECURE, NONSECURE, or SECURE_BOOTLOADER (e.g. -Wl,-DSECURE)."
    ^~~~~~~
..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld:149:6: warning: #warning "Secure app length (AS_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DAS_SIZE=size). Assuming half of ROM (0x40000 bytes)." [-Wcpp]
 #    warning "Secure app length (AS_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DAS_SIZE=size). Assuming half of ROM (0x40000 bytes)."
      ^~~~~~~
..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld:163:6: warning: #warning "Non-secure callable length (ANSC_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DANSC_SIZE=size). Assuming 0 bytes." [-Wcpp]
 #    warning "Non-secure callable length (ANSC_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DANSC_SIZE=size). Assuming 0 bytes."
      ^~~~~~~
..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld:169:4: warning: #warning "Boot protection size (BOOTPROT_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DBOOTPROT_SIZE=size). Assuming 0 bytes." [-Wcpp]
 #  warning "Boot protection size (BOOTPROT_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DBOOTPROT_SIZE=size). Assuming 0 bytes."
    ^~~~~~~
..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld:174:4: warning: #warning "Secure SRAM length (RS_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DRS_SIZE=size). Assuming half of SRAM (0x8000 bytes)." [-Wcpp]
 #  warning "Secure SRAM length (RS_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DRS_SIZE=size). Assuming half of SRAM (0x8000 bytes)."
    ^~~~~~~

Info: Loading file: ./..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld
make[4]: Leaving directory '[...]/test/Secure/firmware/test_Secure.X'
make[3]: Leaving directory '[...]/test/Secure/firmware/test_Secure.X'
make[2]: Leaving directory '[...]/test/Secure/firmware/test_Secure.X'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-test.mk dist/test/production/test_NonSecure.X.production.hex
make[2]: Entering directory '[...]/test/NonSecure/firmware/test_NonSecure.X'
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"   -mprocessor=32CM5164LS00064  -o dist/test/production/test_NonSecure.X.production.elf build/test/production/_ext/1363761897/plib_nvic.o build/test/production/_ext/1363815048/plib_port.o build/test/production/_ext/1158042722/plib_sercom3_usart.o build/test/production/_ext/1918410531/xc32_monitor.o build/test/production/_ext/340140899/exceptions.o build/test/production/_ext/340140899/initialization.o build/test/production/_ext/340140899/interrupts.o build/test/production/_ext/340140899/libc_syscalls.o build/test/production/_ext/340140899/startup_xc32.o build/test/production/_ext/1360937237/main.o          -DXPRJ_test=test      -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1,--script="..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld",--defsym=_min_heap_size=0,--gc-sections,-Map="dist/test/production/test_NonSecure.X.production.map",--memorysummary,dist/test/production/memoryfile.xml -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS00"
..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld:143:4: warning: #warning "Defaulting to a SECURE TrustZone-M project. Please define the linker macro SECURE, NONSECURE, or SECURE_BOOTLOADER (e.g. -Wl,-DSECURE)." [-Wcpp]
 #  warning "Defaulting to a SECURE TrustZone-M project. Please define the linker macro SECURE, NONSECURE, or SECURE_BOOTLOADER (e.g. -Wl,-DSECURE)."
    ^~~~~~~
nbproject/Makefile-test.mk:245: recipe for target 'dist/test/production/test_NonSecure.X.production.hex' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory '[...]/test/NonSecure/firmware/test_NonSecure.X'
..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld:149:6: warning: #warning "Secure app length (AS_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DAS_SIZE=size). Assuming half of ROM (0x40000 bytes)." [-Wcpp]
nbproject/Makefile-test.mk:88: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '[...]/test/NonSecure/firmware/test_NonSecure.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
 #    warning "Secure app length (AS_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DAS_SIZE=size). Assuming half of ROM (0x40000 bytes)."
      ^~~~~~~
..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld:163:6: warning: #warning "Non-secure callable length (ANSC_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DANSC_SIZE=size). Assuming 0 bytes." [-Wcpp]
 #    warning "Non-secure callable length (ANSC_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DANSC_SIZE=size). Assuming 0 bytes."
      ^~~~~~~
..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld:169:4: warning: #warning "Boot protection size (BOOTPROT_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DBOOTPROT_SIZE=size). Assuming 0 bytes." [-Wcpp]
 #  warning "Boot protection size (BOOTPROT_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DBOOTPROT_SIZE=size). Assuming 0 bytes."
    ^~~~~~~
..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld:174:4: warning: #warning "Secure SRAM length (RS_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DRS_SIZE=size). Assuming half of SRAM (0x8000 bytes)." [-Wcpp]
 #  warning "Secure SRAM length (RS_SIZE) not specified (e.g. -Wl,-DRS_SIZE=size). Assuming half of SRAM (0x8000 bytes)."
    ^~~~~~~
c:\program files\microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\bin\..\..\lib\gcc\pic32c\8.3.1\..\..\..\..\bin\bin/pic32c-ld.exe: build/test/production/_ext/1360937237/main.o: in function `main':
[...]\test\NonSecure\firmware\test_NonSecure.X/../src/main.c:99: undefined reference to `secure_add'
c:\program files\microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\bin\..\..\lib\gcc\pic32c\8.3.1\..\..\..\..\bin\bin/pic32c-ld.exe: [...]\test\NonSecure\firmware\test_NonSecure.X/../src/main.c:114: undefined reference to `secure_multiply'

Info: Loading file: ./..\src\config\pic32cm_ls00_cpro\PIC32CM5164LS00100.ld
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 255 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/test/production/test_NonSecure.X.production.hex] Error 255
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

I have tried the suggested answer from the Microchip forums (found here: https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/Default-TrustZone-32-bit-MCC-Harmony-project-does-not-build--MPLAB-X-IDE-6-05--MCC-5-2-2), but when opening MCC to generate code & project configuration for the Secure project, the following error appears: "Unable to load project: Incompatible with core: Harmony V3 v1.3.0".
Help is appreciated!